# How to model this organic leaf structure?

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

I am trying to make this fungi-looking leaf structure shown in the image. I am able to make the overall fungi-looking structure, but the problem is that it is in the shape of the object I create it with, like a plane. I want to have a different edge, like in the image. Also, there's a middle stem in all of the shapes, but I can't figure out how to include that geometry. I would appreciate any information that could help me.

Comment: Hi Weird Panda! How familiar are you with 3d modeling in Blender? Can you edit your question and show us a screenshot of your progress? This way we can help better in offering you a solution.

Comment: Hi Rumen! Thank you for responding. I am not so familiar with modelling in Blender, especially with more organic structures. I have only worked on hard-surface objects before, and I have added a current screenshot of what I've done. I can only make a vaguely similar-looking organic structure, which I learned from a tutorial. I hope this helps, and you can help me in any way. Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to look for 'organic modeling'. I've never done it myself but with the Tissue addon one can get these kind of models. Some links: [the addon](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tissue.html)  or [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dtf5nhe5bac) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-0NzU1TmIY) on youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Shout out to [Irene Laschi](https://www.behance.net/gallery/29820527/Micosan), who's wonderful hand drawn illustration we are trying to recreate.**

*A basic knowledge of editing meshes menus, using Modifiers and Sculpt mode  is required.*

The steps bellow show an approach on how to model the "leaves" which resemble a mixture of slime mold and dried plant leaf structures:

[image]

1. Start from **Top** view, add a **Plane** object and subdivide sequentially twice while shaping the overall shape of the leaf.
2. Add a **Subdivision Surface** modifier with level 2 to smooth out the shape and add extra geometry to the plane.
3. Add **Decimate** modifier to triangulate and reduce the subdivided faces. View the **Wireframe** to observe how the settings change the triangulation.
4. Add **Geometry Node** modifier with the simple node set up - include only the **Dual Mesh** node with default settings.
5. **Apply all modifiers** so far and enter **Edit** mode to delete any loose vertices.
6. In **Edit mode** - subdivide all edges once more and slightly **Smooth** the mesh vertices.
7. Select all faces and use the **Inset** operation (hotkey [I]) with **Individual** option turned on (check the operator settings). Make a small inset inwards and **delete the selected Faces**.
8. **Extrude** part of the border where the trunk will be. At this stage you can **Tweak** the vertices to shape the mesh.
9. Select the vertices that will represent the trunk and branches and assign them to a **Vertex Group** named "*Trunk*".
10. Optionally you can smooth the vertices weight in **Weight Paint** mode.
11. Add a **Solidify** Modifier with **Offset** = 1, **Thickness** = 0.065 and **Only Rim** option **On**. Choose "*Trunk*" vertex group and set the **Factor** to about 0.5
12. Add **Mirror** modifier with Z as mirror axis
13. Add **Subdivision Surface** Modifier with subdivision level 2
14. **Apply all modifiers** and enter **Sculpt** mode. Using the **Grab** brush and appropriate brush size gently adjust the shape to emphasize and straighten  the trunk and branches. Use **Inflate** brush to adjust the girth of the trunk and branches. Use **Smooth** brush to smooth the structures - less at the center, more at the ends. You can enable Z axis symmetry to apply the brushes on both sides of the symmetry plane.

Here is an animated version of the steps above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Rumen, for the help. This helped me a lot, and now I understand how to model the shape, so again, thanks a lot! Also, shout out to Irene Laschi for the amazing illustration.